# CSS font-size does not work after setting body.style.fontSize

Tags: javascript, css

After setting document.body.style.fontSize to a certain size using an window.onload function, all elements under *body* have the same size, even thought I have specified in their CSS class that their font-size should be 40% of their parent element.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Where is your code? It's impossible to help you with a javascript/CSS problem if we _can't see the javascript/CSS_!

Comment: Sorry Kyle, the CSS can be found in: http://pastebin.com/HsWU38LC and the javascript code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365699/mobile-website-font-sizing-and-wrapping. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript modification comes after the CSS has been loaded. So all elements in your body are impacted. You should apply your modification to just the bunch of elements you want to modify.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without iterating over all elements? (like group based?) The function I am using for the resize is detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365699/mobile-website-font-sizing-and-wrapping